# Oracle Reports Builder RDF to PDF output, Some Spanish Characters being replaced automatically with special characters

Tags: character, report, builder, spanish

Oracle Reports Builder RDF to PDF output, Some Spanish Characters being replaced automatically with special characters. Please suggest how when I copy spanish text from a MS-Word RTF file into a text item of Oracle Reports Builder Layout. It copies fine, but when run from EBS concurrent manager, the PDF output replaces spanish characters with a mark on the top, with some other special characters... see examples in bold below.

T**Ã‰**RMINOS Y CONDICIONES REGULARES DE COMPRA DE COPELAND (ARGENTINA) Los t**Ã©**rminos y condiciones establecidos en adelante ("TÃ©rminos y Condiciones") regularÃ¡n la compra de equipos y servicios realizada por Copeland Argentina, S.R.L. (el "Comprador" o "Copeland"), los cuales son de aplicaci**Ã³**n obligatoria para Copeland y el Proveedor. AdemÃ¡s de las definiciones incluidas a lo largo de estos TÃ©rminos y Condiciones, los siguientes tÃ©rminos, al ser escritos en may**Ãº**scula, tendrÃ¡n los siguientes significados a efectos de interpretar la Orden de Compra: Provisi**Ã³**n: significa el diseÃ±o, bienes, materiales, equipos y/o servicios a ser suministrados de acuerdo con los tÃ©rminos y condiciones especificados en la Orden de Compra. Comprador: significa Copeland Argentina, S.R.L., ya sea que actÃºe por cuenta propia o por cuenta y orden de terceros. En el caso donde el Comprador no sea el beneficiario final de la ProvisiÃ³n, todos los derechos adquiridos mediante la Orden de Compra serÃ¡n en beneficio del Propietario. Proveedor: significa la persona fÃ-sica o jurÃ-dica a la cual se dirige la Orden de Compra emitida. Sub-proveedor: se refiere a cualquier persona fÃ-sica o jurÃ-dica vinculada, en forma directa o indirecta, a la ProvisiÃ³n, ya sea mediante contrato con el Proveedor, en calidad de contratista o subcontratista, o mediante cualquier otro tipo de relaciÃ³n. Propietario: designa al beneficiario final de la ProvisiÃ³n, el adquiriente de los derechos sobre el objeto de la Orden de Compra, una vez perfeccionada la misma. Orden de Compra: define al acuerdo, en su total alcance, entre el Comprador y el Proveedor, en los tÃ©rminos y condiciones que se estipulen en los instrumentos respectivos, incluyendo la Orden de Compra, estos TÃ©rminos y Condiciones, planos, diagramas, hojas de datos, anexos y ampliaciones. Precio de la Orden de Compra: refiere al monto exigible por el Proveedor al Comprador como contraprestaciÃ³n por el cumplimiento en tiempo y forma de la ProvisiÃ³n indicada en la Orden de Compra. 1. ALCANCE DEL ACUERDO 1.1 La Orden de Compra, los TÃ©rminos

Comment: what is character set for your Report builder, it should be UTF-8